# What do would you recommend for Java code analysis (if anything)?

Tags: java, code-analysis

Let's risk this rephrasing of a question posted under Programmers.

We're looking for something to run as part of our (Java) CI process for finding bugs, formatting issues and reporting on code coverage.

Ideally this would:

- Integrate with Travis CI, GitHub and / or Maven
- Be maintained enough to deal with more modern Java syntax e.g. Java 8
- Make recommendations for improvements and refactoring

What would you use for this?

If you don't use these kinds of tools or think static analysis is not useful, is there a completely different approach to maintaining and improving code quality that you could recommend instead?

Comment: I have used jetbrains https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-inspections-offline.html problem is I don't know if you could integrate it with what you want.

Comment: I think you have multiple questions here because of the different emphases.   Can't you decouple these, (e.g., test coverage for java has lots of available tools)?  Are  you interested in code quality issues such as duplicated code detection?